# How does one delete one's StackOverflow Account?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

It is much too difficult to post legitimate questions on this site.

How does one delete one's account if one has voted or posted in the past?

Comment: If you don't want your name associated with the site (as stated in your profile), you can just change it

Comment: I prefer total deletion. Please instruct.

Comment: Sorry you've gotten so discouraged. Sure you don't want to sleep on it? You actually have a decent amount of reputation built up.

Comment: What's to sleep about? I am not a fan of stifling legitimate questions of support that may not meet the political correctness o a few.

Comment: Deletion is the only way he can "get back" at an organization he's frustrated with.

Comment: Senor? Do you know my story? Why so presumptuous? Your comment epitomizes my disdain for this site.

Comment: You can't be anything but presumptuous on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, just follow these instructions.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. (whom am I talking to, by the way?)